# How to modify cell content in (data bound) ListView.oniteminvoked event? [W8 Metro UI, WinJS]

Tags: javascript, listview, microsoft-metro, refresh, databound

I created a data bound listview in a Windows 8 HTML5/JavaScript app, I would like to modify the data bound to the clicked cell. For this I am using the ListView.oniteminvoked event.

The data is successfully modified, but the cell does not refresh.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211827.aspx) says I should probably use "msSetImmediate", but I cannot understand how.

How to refresh the single cell? Could you provide me an example in which once clicked, the cell changes its content based on the modified data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem (somehow) solved:

```
eventObject.detail.itemPromise.done(function (invokedItem) {
    DataExample.data[invokedItem.index] = { newobject }
    dataList.setAt(invokedItem.index, { newobject });
});
```

Alas, `setAt` - although actually refreshes the cell contents - does not seem to modify the data array used to create the dataList, hence I am updating it manually before.